# Does not paying for a conference mean one's paper becomes unaccepted?

Tags: publications, conference

I have a paper accepted at X conference. It has a very expensive registration fee which I was told would be paid by my advisor. But now they are not going to pay.

1. If I don't pay the fee, does that mean that the paper has become unaccepted?
2. Can I mention it in my CV and just say that it was accepted but not paid for?

It was an abstract paper and they will be having a book of abstracts, but I'm sure if I don't pay my abstract will not be there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it okay to leave a conference paper as a pre-print?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/164348/is-it-okay-to-leave-a-conference-paper-as-a-pre-print)

Comment: Haha, it actually doesn't. I can't upload this as a pre-print!

Comment: @Aymuos why can't you do that?

Answer (score 4):

I think this will depend on conference policy, but in general if you have to pay even though being a presenter (some conferences will waive the fee if you do a presentation, but that doesn't seem to be the case here), not paying the fee means they are going to cancel your presentation. Most often, they communicate this when confirming that your abstract has been accepted (e.g. "If the registration fee is not payed until the ..., your submission cannot be considered.")

What you could try, though, is contacting the conference organizers and explain your situation - maybe they will make an exception and allow you to attend (and present) without paying because of your special circumstances. It doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: I don't think I can send an email. The advisor is actually a co-author in the paper so they will find out.

Comment: Why is them finding out a problem? Presumably they know you would like to attend.

Comment: So, your advisor is a coauthor but is okay with the paper getting unaccepted if you don’t pay the registration fee? And why are you being secretive and wanting to do things without your advisor (who is also your coauthor) knowing about it? It seems like there’s more going on here than what your question states, and you may have worse problems related to your relationship with your advisor than just the lack of money for the registration fee…